# Scrollview not creating through programmatically

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I want to creat a scrollview programmatically but the scroll view is not creating the below is my code i want to display images in that scrollview.

```
fscroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view1.frame.size.width, self.view1.frame.size.height)];
fscroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 400);
fscroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
fscroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
[view1 addSubview:fscroll];

int X=0;
for (int i = 0; i < [images count]; i++)
{

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(X, 0, 320, 480)];
     imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     [imageView setImage: [images objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]];

    [imageView addSubview:fscroll];

    X = X + imageView.frame.size.height;

    if(X > 320)
        self.fscroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(X, 134);

    if(X > 320)
        self.fscroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(X, 134);
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding scrollview to an image? Are you sure you want to do it?

Comment: i am adding images to scrollview sir.but the scrollview is not creating

Comment: Yes, I think what you really want to do is [fscroll addSubview:imageView]

Comment: yes i edit that was my fault but basically the scrollview is not displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
X = X + imageView.frame.size.height;
```

Did you mean to do this?

```
X = X + imageView.frame.size.width;
```

EDIT: Also, are you sure view1 has the right frame set before your UIScrollView is initialized?

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong: `[imageView addSubview:fscroll];` Presumable you want to do `[fscroll addSubview:imageView];`

Comment: i edit that but the the main problem with scrollview it cannto working

Answer (score 0):

Simple Method: You can created multiple times if you need means

```
- (void)scrollView
{


    int x = 0; //scrollview width
    int y = 10;//scrollview height
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        UIScrollView *scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 50, 50)];
        scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
        scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
        scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
        scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(50,50);
        x=x+55;


    }
}
```